# I was trying to describe a recipe to my friend that I'd had a go of

Tags: phrases, syntactic-analysis, dialects, relative-clauses

Is this dialectal use:

> And I thought I've got a nice kitchen now maybe I should learn to cook. And I'm learning, it's going quite well. I don't always know the right words for things. I couldn't remember the word marinade recently when I was trying to describe a recipe to my friend that I'd **had a go of.**

Source: 33:13, Youtube video '[Home Bird (2014) FULL SHOW - Sarah Millican](https://youtu.be/Jvx2USgy9Bs?t=1953)'

I understand that she "had a go AT the recipe" (not at her friend).
Now, what is the longest acceptable distance between the noun and the start of the relative clause that refers to it?

How acceptable is the sentence

**I was trying to describe a recipe to my friend you saw me with last night at the karaoke competition that I'd had a go of.**

or

**I was trying to describe a recipe to my friend you saw me with last night at our company's office that I'd had a go of.**

Comment: Really, in the last two sentences it would be much better to write **"I was trying to describe a recipe I'd had a go of to my friend who you saw me with last night at the karaoke competition."**

Comment: **Informal** rather than **dialect**. (And, as others have said, _had a go at_ would be much more usual.)

Comment: Sarah Millican does use dialect for comedic value. She uses her native dialect, Geordie, & pushes it. Even to a British ear Geordie is 'very non-standard' compared to some. Comparisons, for those unfamiliar - 'Oz' 'Dennis' & 'Neville' from [Auf Wiedersehen Pet](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Auf_Wiedersehen,_Pet),  Cheryl Cole, Pop stars, Girls Aloud, The X Factor. (You can search YouTube for audio/video examples.)

Comment: She's a hysterical comic. Irish? She can use whatever wording she wants for effect, even *fester* instead of *marinade*, without our edits.

Comment: @YosefBaskin - 'Geordie' (North-eastern England), not Irish.

Answer (score 2):

[Merriam Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/have%20a%20go) licenses 'have a go **at**, with 'at' the transitivising particle:

> *have a go* [idiom]: to try to do something
>
> - "*I can't get the window open*." __"*Let me have a go* (*at it*)."

Likewise, [Collins, citing Webster’s New World College Dictionary](https://www.collinsdictionary.com/dictionary/english/have-a-go-at), licenses **only** the 'have a go at' version, with no corresponding entry for 'have a go of':

> *have a go at* ... [Informal]: to try; attempt
>
> Examples of 'have a go at' in a sentence:
>
> - *Well, I would like to have a go at that trailer he lives in*. [Wilcox, James SORT OF RICH (1990)] ...
> - *Have a go at wood carving, shelter building and making a bow and arrow.* [The Sun (2018)]

This concurs with my opinion that 'have a go of' is non-standard or dialect. It reminds me of 'try and [be good]', though that is much better attested.

There are, however, internet examples such as

> - *So book now to have a go of pottery, spinning and weaving* ... [Scottish Crannog Centre]
> - *Keep an eye out for: ...  Our new Anatomy Centre – where you can have a go of the anatomage table* [[University of Sunderland ...
>   student
>   experience](https://www.sunderland.ac.uk/student-experience/explore/preparing-for-university/reasons-open-day/)]
> - *I just had to have a go of these sakura nails when I seen them* ... [TikTok]

and a venerable but I'd say archaic example

> - "*Let's have a go of the rum*.” ('Treasure Island'; Robert Louis Stevenson)

But I'd say these Google ngrams tell the true story:

[image]

It's a minority variant – and that's a tiny minority. Better to stick with the idiomatic expression.

Comment: I said `try and <verb>` all the time as a kid until it was educated out of me. It's extremely common in AmE. *I'm going to try and finish up early today to beat the rush-hour traffic.* or "I'm going to try and be a nicer coach and not make you guys run sprints until you puke. But not today."

Comment: "Try and" is standard. I'd bet a million dollars you say it occasionally without realising it.

Comment: @Araucaria-Nothereanymore. According to _Practical English Usage_  "try and" is informal. According to CoGEL it is _rather informal_, and the use of "and" in this construction is termed pseudo-coordination.

Comment: @LPH Exactly. It's standard.

Comment: I'm not sure RLS used 'try and'. Not that I'd mark it as incorrect. But I avoid using it.

Comment: @EdwinAshworth He sure did. All over the place. [For example, here](http://www.literaturepage.com/read/kidnapped-183.html).  "Davie, ye'll have to try and forgive me".

Comment: He is 'quoting' here, along with "I'll find a house to ye, David", "Do ye gang easier so, Davie?" and "Wheesht, wheesht!"...  Though admittedly I didn't know RLS personally. // According to [this article from Northern Illinois University](https://www.niu.edu/writingtutorial/style/formal-and-informal-style.shtml#:~:text=Formal%20language%20is%20characterized%20by,and%20typically%20shorter%20sentence%20structures.),  'Informal language allows the use of nonstandard English forms, colloquial vocabulary and typically shorter sentence structures.' 'Informal English' is not a subset of 'standard E'.